# Matlab how to create n arrays of equal size matrices from an array of different size matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array of different size matrices.I would like to create n arrays each including equal size matrices. So if I have:

```
 ArrayA =
 <9x10 double>
 <7x10 double>
 <9x10 double>
 <9x10 double>
 <7x10 double>
```

I would like to obtain:

```
ArrayA1 =
<9x10 double>
<9x10 double>
<9x10 double>

ArrayA2 =    
<7x10 double>
<7x10 double>
```

Comment: yes, they all have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat = 

[4x5 double]
[4x5 double]
[5x5 double]
[4x5 double]
[5x5 double]
[6x5 double]
[5x5 double]
```

I assume all are `nx5`, thus only rows are checked.

```
arr_sizes =  arrayfun(@(x) size(mat{x},1),1:size(mat,1))'
```

This gives:

```
arr_sizes =

 4
 4
 5
 4
 5
 6
 5
```

Now:

```
[~, ~, idx] = unique(arr_sizes);
```

The final output will be:

```
tot_arr = arrayfun(@(x) mat(idx == x), 1:max(idx),'UniformOutput',false)';

tot_arr =

{3x1 cell}
{3x1 cell}
{1x1 cell}
```

Now, `tot_arr` contains 3 arrays, the ones you called `ArrayA1, ArrayA2` etc.

```
tot_arr{1}

ans = 

[4x5 double]
[4x5 double]
[4x5 double]
```